# Why did k3sup install failed? Error: unable to connect to 192.168.33.1:22 over ssh

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have VM on my Laptop,I want to install k3s on it(from remote)

```
k3sup install   --ip 192.168.33.1   --cluster   --user miki   --k3s-channel stable   --local-path ~/.kube/config   --merge --context k3s   --k3s-extra-args '--no-deploy traefik --write-kubeconfig-mode 644'
Running: k3sup install
2023/07/13 12:26:38 192.168.33.1
Public IP: 192.168.33.1
Error: unable to connect to 192.168.33.1:22 over ssh: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

ip a shows

```
85: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.33.1/24 brd 192.168.33.255 scope global vboxnet1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can vagrant ssh from my comp.

What does none publickey mean?